# AzureAD OpenID Connect JWT "platf" claim value

Tags: azure, entra-id, single-sign-on, openid, mdm

I am setting up an application that will use AzureAD as an OpenID Connect IDP for authentication. I want to know if the authenticating device is an AzureAD "managed" or "compliant" [device](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/overview#device-management) at the application level by checking the returned [JWT access token](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens). There is an optional ["platf" JWT claim](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims#configuring-groups-optional-claims) that can be configured on the AzureAD SSO application dashboard and is described as "Restricted to managed devices that can verify device type". I enabled the claim and observed it is a number in the access JWT token returned by AzureAD. I assume it maps to an enum; however, I cant find any documentation about what status each integer indicates. Has anyone used this claim or know what it represents? Or perhaps a different method of determining if the authenticating device is AzureAD managed?

Comment: It's not a standard claim as per the openid connect spec and googling for "platfm" gives nothing whatsover. At the bottom of the microsoft doc there is a comment section and links to the doc repo on github. I think you want to try contacting them there. Nobody but the guy who implemented that would have a clue. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims#configuring-groups-optional-claims

Comment: @user5994461 Already did that, no response yet :( https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/52310